# What are "retirable" entities in Guidewire?

Tags: guidewire

Can you explain what are "retirable" entities in guidewire? How can we create these entities?
Also explain what is the difference between effdated entities and retirable entities?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retirable entity is an extension of Editable entity. It has Retired field (boolean field) to do a logic delete.
EffDated entity also is an extension of Editable entity. It has EffectiveDate (Start date) and ExpirationDate (End date).

There are several differences but maybe the most interest for you is that effdated entity is used for entities that you are interest in know whole history (by example PolicyPeriod), then when you "deleted" an effdated item a new item is created with ExpirationDate modified to do a logic deleted.